# Adding an ID attribute in the CButtonColumn not working

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

```
<?php 
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'material-logs-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$materialLogSearch->search(),
            'filter'=>$materialLogSearch,
            'ajaxUpdate'=> true,
            'columns'=>array(
                'po_number',
                'qty_ordered',
                array(
                    'name'=>'price',
                    'value'=>'number_format($data->price,2)',
                    'type'=>'raw'
                ),
                array(
                    'name'=>'price',
                    'header'=>'Amount',
                    'value'=>'number_format($data->price*$data->qty_ordered,2)',
                    'type'=>'raw'
                ),
                'date_ordered',
                'note',
                array(
                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                    'template'=>'{update}{delete}',
                    'buttons'=>array(
                        'update'=>array(
                            'options'=>array(
                                'id'=>"myID-$data->idMaterial_logs",
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'updateButtonUrl'=>"Yii::app()->createUrl(\"materialLogs/update\",array(\"id\"=>\$data->idMaterial_logs,\"pid\"=>\"$project_details->idProject\",\"mid\"=>\$data->idMaterials))",
                    'deleteButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/materialLogs/delete",array("id"=>$data->idMaterial_logs))',
                ),
            ),
        ));
        ?>
```

I'm getting this error

```
Undefined variable: data
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
'id'=>"myID-$data->idMaterial_logs",
```

What's the proper way to add an ID attribute on the CButtonColumn? I just wanted the Update Button to have a custom ID with it's corresponding id that is from my database(`$data->idMaterials`);

So for example:
the id should be "myID-1", the 1 there is the value of idMaterial_logs, that is why I use $data->idMaterial_logs, which in this case it did not work.

Your help will be greatly appreciated and rewarded! Thanks! :)

Comment: what do you want the id to be like? sample?

Comment: @bool.dev the id should be "myID-1", the 1 there is the value of idMaterial_logs, that is why I use $data->idMaterial_logs, which in this case it did not work.

Comment: well `$data` is not available in `options` for buttons, you might have to extend `CButtonColumn`

Comment: Oh, really? is there a way without extending? because that's a very hassle work on just a very simple expected result.

Comment: not that i am aware of, you can take a look at [this wiki article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/314/cgridview-use-special-variable-data-in-the-htmloptions-of-a-column-i-e-evaluate-htmloptions-attribute/) for hints on implementing a similar solution for your custom, say MButtonColumn class. Or may be [this wiki's](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/372/cbuttoncolumn-use-special-variable-data-for-the-id-in-the-options-of-a-button) way.

Comment: what do you need the link id value for? I think there might be better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove myID

```
'id'=>"myID-$data->idMaterial_logs",
```

To be

```
'id'=>'$data->idMaterial_logs',
```

Comment: that value wont be eval'd anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is taht you're using double quotes (") instead of single quotes (')
Because of this, the file will look for $data inside the view. It doesn't exist there.

Try this

```
<?php
'id' => '"myID-".$data->idMaterial_logs',
```